# Multiple events in the achivements when user was removed

Tags: bug, reputation, deleted-accounts

According to the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed), e.g. on Stack Oveflow (emphasis is mine):

> All the reputation changes from a single user's deletion are rolled into a **single event** in the reputation page labelled "User was removed".

But I see multiple events in [my profile](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/alexolut?tab=reputation&sort=post) on Stack Overflow in Russian:

> [image: retract]

One message (20:41) says "User was removed", and the rest (all 20:40) say "unupvote". For most posts unupvoting is not possible due to lack of post edits, i.e. vote should be locked on them. Hence I think it's a bug.

Comment: Try waiting for some time, see if it gets folded in. It could otherwise be voting fraud being reversed. Either way, we need an SE employee to investigate.

Answer (score 3):

It looks as if voting fraud was reversed here. The user may have serially upvoted you, and that was undone - either by the script or manually by a Community Team member.

When the serial voting detection script reverts votes, it is usually rolled into a single event, as Sonic points out in their [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305930/multiple-events-in-the-achivements-when-user-was-removed/305931#comment994418_305931). When a CT member needs to get involved, they may have to investigate the suspicious votes separately, hence this resulting in separate unupvotes/undownvotes.

It is very well possible that the serial voter is the same user that got deleted, but it doesn't have to be.

Comment: If it was serial voting, it would show a single statement "voting corrected", not a bunch of different "unupvote" statements.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog On one occassion, some serial voting on my own profile on SO was not undone by the script. I flagged for moderator attention, and a few days later the serially voted posts got un{up|down}voted.

Comment: It likely only applies if it's automatically undone by the script, then.

Comment: It was probably undone by a moderator because as far as I know, the script only runs at 3.00 UTC, and here the voting was reversed at 20.40 UTC.